# "object is not extensible" error trying to add field in map function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add a new field to items in an array with map:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
    return (item.newField = 'Something');
});
```

And Ive tried:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
    item.newField = 'Something';
    return item;
});
```

However I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property newField, object is not extensible
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare `item.newField` or assign it? The syntax used here is intended to do a comparison, so you need `===`

Comment: Im trying to assign a new field. Item will always be returned.

Comment: item may be a primitive.

Comment: Ah! Then you need to use `Object.assign` here. `oldArray.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { newField: 'Something' }));`

Comment: You need to make a copy of the object in order to assign a new property here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the Object is marked as not extensible and you are running strict mode.

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible

When the method `Object.preventExtensions(obj)` is called, you get the error.

```
'use strict';

var obj = {};
Object.preventExtensions(obj);

obj.x = 'foo';
```

You will get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property x, object is not extensible`

Comment: While this is true it can cause the error, it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
  return Object.assign({}, item, { newField: 'Something' });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use const and return here, `Object.assign({}` returns a shallow clone, and a single line lamba (arrow function) has an implied return

Answer (score 2):

you could use object spread (es6 feature) like so:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
    // { ...item } creates a new object and spreads all of "item" items
    // into it. We can then assign a "newField" or overwrite "newField" 
    // if it already exists on "item"
    return { ...item, newField: 'something' };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also clone the object via `Object.create(...)`

```
const object1 = {
  foo: 'foo'
};

// This will prevent extending this object:
Object.preventExtensions(object1);

const object2 = Object.create(object1);

/**
 * This cloned object has no preventExtensions flag
 * and can thus be extended as you like
 */
object2.bar = 'bar';
```