# TypeError: Cannot add property newField, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting error

> TypeError: Cannot add property newField, object is not extensible

While adding any new key or changing any value is not happeing don't know what is wrong.

```
 dynamicFilter;

 public ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.commonservice.showLoading();
    this.store.dispatch(activeBookingActions.getBookingFiltersRequest());
    this.bookingFilterSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(selectActiveBookingData)).subscribe(response => {
      this.commonservice.hideLoading();
      if (response.bookingdata && response.bookingdata.filterlist && response.bookingdata.filterlist.data && (response.bookingdata.filterlist.data.action === 'bookingFilters')) {
        this.commonservice.hideLoading();
        this.filterList = response.bookingdata.filterlist.data.list;
        this.sortingList = this.filterList.sorting;
        this.dynamicFilter = [...this.filterList.filter];
        console.log(this.dynamicFilter);

         this.dynamicFilter.forEach((x) => {
           if (x.design_type == 'checkbox') {
             x.design_type = 'sadas';     // this line giving error
           }
         });
      }
    });
  }
```

Tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022130/12917651

With no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you get the data from a store or NgRx where you can't modify the data directly (ngrx-store-freeze).

Try creating copy of the object of each item in the array as well.

```
this.dynamicFilter = this.filterList.filter.map(data => ({ ...data }));
        console.log(this.dynamicFilter);

         this.dynamicFilter.forEach((x) => {
           if (x.design_type == 'checkbox') {
             x.design_type = 'sadas';     // this line giving error
           }
         });
```

Map will transform the array immutably and each object in the array gets spread to a new location in memory with the spread operator (...).